# simple flexbox grid overflow fit to row height

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, overflow

I have a very simple grid using flexbox where I want to display multi-line data in a scrollable box. I might be missing a trivial property but the row height doesn't appear to adjust itself properly to the height of it's content.

An example: https://plnkr.co/edit/rCXfvd4Vsh8RgoFja89A?p=preview

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.grid .header {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.grid .row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.grid .row:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC;
}

.grid .col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
}

.grid .col-2 {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox grid</h1>

<h3>Overflow example</h3>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-2">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">One Line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">One Line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>No overflow example</h3>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-2">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

To keep everything simple I my columns are fixed size and all the data I want to display is loaded into the grid (instead of using a virtual grid). Is there a way to fix my example so that the rows adjust itself to the content?

**EDIT**: **SOLVED!**

As user @bhv pointed out I should have disabled shrink on `.row` by applying `flex: 1 0 auto` instead of `flex+:1 (1 auto)`.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.grid .header {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.grid .row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.grid .row:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC;
}

.grid .col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
}

.grid .col-2 {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox grid</h1>

<h3>Overflow example</h3>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-2">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">One Line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">One Line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>No overflow example</h3>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-2">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row body">
    <div class="col-1">DATA</div>
    <div class="col-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jIoaME?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jIoaME?p=preview

Comment: Oh wow.. I just had to disable the 'shrink' property? I've completely overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the total height of your items is higher than their parents `max-height`, and since the `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, they will shrink as much as possible to fit.

So by simply change `flex-shrink` to `0` will prevent that.

Also the `flex: 1` cause another change of the defaults, where the `flex-basis` is set to `0`, which will make the items share the space left equally, instead of the default `auto`, which takes their content into account before the remaining space is calculated.

In your case though, where the parent has no height (and `flex-direction: column`), `flex: 1` has no effect and can be deleted.